# How can I refresh expired Guardian access token in Elixir

Tags: elixir, guardian

Is there the way to refresh Guardian access token, if the one is expired?

Answer (score 1):

Expired tokens cannot be used by definition. You should refresh a token before it expires. Per package [readme](https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian#basics), you would do it like this:

> ```
> # Refresh a token before it expires
> {:ok, _old_stuff, {new_token, new_claims}} = MyApp.Guardian.refresh(token)
> ```